# migrate data to artifactory v7

Tags: npm, artifactory

i want to migrate some npm packages from artifactory v6 to v7. i use jfrog cli to download from v6 and upload to v7 and structure is okay. but when i try to pull package from v7 i got this error

```
verbose 0.382448348 Performing "GET" request to "https://artifactory-update.sanpp.tech/api/npm/npm/@sanpp%2fcache".
verbose 0.44435342 Request "https://artifactory-update.sanpp.tech/api/npm/npm/@sanpp%2fcache" finished with status code 404.
verbose 0.456810004 Error: Couldn't find package "@sanpp/cache" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:50489:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:321:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
error Couldn't find package "@sanpp/cache" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

all the packages are the same(even the size but it didn't get that)

also looks like there must be some metadata in artifactory v7 but i don't find any way to regenerate it

Comment: Is it possible you are missing the '/artifactory' context? In 7.x it is required.
You may want to check if the file exists and how the request is reaching Artifactory in the artifactory-request.log